# Django Model field validation vs DRF Serializer field validation

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

The field validation process can happen in **'Django Model level field declaration'** or in **'Deserialization of data on DRF serialization section'**. I have the following concerns regarding this validation process:

- What is the separation of concerns? Which validation section should be placed where?
- How the DRF serialization section restricts manual database entry with the validation?

Answer (score 4):

Serializers are concerned with translating information to/from different formats for a model (text/json, etc.), and so the validation is in reference to this.

Model validation is a lower-level check, where the creation/modification of a db model is done. I always have model validation, even if I have serialization validation.

Answer (score -1):

I think the difference can be understood with the following example .

Let's say a college A has maxmimum seats available are 200 in CS Stream and college B has maximum seats 500 for CS stream for this scenerio field validation at serializers makes sense

Now let's assume if there is a restriction on the number of student that are allowed in CS Stream for all colleges the we should use the Model level field validation

I hope this helps